# How to use Window Manager of Linux inside VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I have the same problem in Redhat Linux and Debian Linux. 
I cannot use the normal switching between windows. 
I mean this square window manager:

[image]

I tried all keys CMD, ALT, CTRL, FN and SHIFT and their combinations unsuccessfully.

In VirtualBox preferences > Input, I have Left CMD as the host key, similarly as explained [here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/change-the-host-key-in-virtualbox/). 
However, I have not managed to use it browse between windows and use the 9-window manager. 
I do not know if the host key is the key which I should be changing.

How can you move between the nine windows in Linux inside VirtualBox?

Comment: Does your VirtualBox  hot key conflict with the modifiers you used?

Comment: @xuhdev Can you give an example shortly what you mean, please? I have disabled all popups from VB.

Comment: [This link](http://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/change-the-host-key-in-virtualbox/) should be helpful

Comment: @xuhdev Can you please provide it as answer and explain little, please. It is old version of virtualbox. I have the key left CMD as the host key but I do not manage to use the 9-window manager.

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to use some acceleration key to switch between workspaces? The default is "Ctrl-Alt-arrow", which you haven't changed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your VirtualBox host key to not conflict with your workspace switching keys.

You can do this by opening the VirtualBox Preference window, select "Input" and change the host key. (Reference: http://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/change-the-host-key-in-virtualbox/)